# Primeng pinput number placeholder doesn't show

Tags: angular, forms, primeng

This is what I tried. What shows is 0.00 instead of the placeholder,
my placeholder is a text like "enter exchange rate"
Any solution for that?

```
<span class="p-inputtext-sm">
            <p-inputNumber [max]="9" mode="decimal" name="exchangeRate" formControlName="exchangeRate"
                [minFractionDigits]="2" [maxFractionDigits]="2" placeholder="exchangeRate"></p-inputNumber>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are initializing your formControl `exchangeRate` with `null` instead of `0`, you can show your placeholder.

Comment: my placeholder is a text like "enter exchange rate". not 0. how can i do that? thanks

Comment: Your question was quite unclear. I will look into it.